# Droppable object isn't resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to drag and drop image and make the cloned droppable image resizable after drop without any luck...

My code is:

```
<img class="dragger" id="obj1" style="cursor: -webkit-grab;float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;" src="objects/bike.png" width="80" height="80">


<img class="dragger" id="obj2" style="cursor: -webkit-grab;float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;" src="objects/car.png" width="80" height="80">


//The dropable div
<div id="contentHolder"></div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

window.zindex = 999;

    //$(".dragger").resizable({handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'});

    $(".dragger").draggable({       
    helper: "clone" 
    }).on('dragstop', function (event, ui) {
    $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());        
    });



$("#contentHolder").droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) {


var id = ui.draggable;

 if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dragger")) {

    $(".dragger").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', "dragger" + (i + 1));
    $(this).removeClass( "dragger" ).addClass("dragger" + (i + 1));
    $("dragger" + (i + 1)).resizable({handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'});
    });


 }


      }    

 });
```

});

Any suggestions why my cloned droppable images isn't resizable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Draggable AND Resizable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948582/jquery-draggable-and-resizable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've got a lot of extra code going on, but the root of your problem is that jQuery is wrapping your image in a `div` when it makes your clone draggable, and the resizable part of the image is actually within that `div` element.

The solution is to add a wrapper element around your images and then make the cloned element draggable and the image inside of it resizable. You also need to add `display: inline-block;` to the CSS of the dragged clone so that the outer div will form itself naturally around the `img` element as it's being resized.

Also, to get this all to fire off correctly, you want to bind all of it to the `stop` event of the draggable element, and not to the `drop` event of the droppable one.

HTML:

```
<div class="dragger">
    <img id="obj1" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
</div>
<div class="dragger">
    <img id="obj2" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
</div>
<div id="contentHolder"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#contentHolder {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    border: 2px dashed #999;
}
.dragger, .dragger-clone {
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dragger").draggable({
        containment: 'html',
        helper: 'clone',
        stop: function (event, ui) {

            /* First, make the clone and append it 
             * to the droppable container
             */
            $(ui.helper)
                .clone(true)
                .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
                .addClass('dragger-clone')
                .appendTo('#contentHolder');

            /* Next, make the clone draggable and 
             * contained by the droppable container
             */
            $(".dragger-clone")
                .draggable({ containment: '#contentHolder' });

            /* Now, make the image within the clone resizable
             */
            $(".dragger-clone img")
                .resizable({handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'});
        }
    });
    $("#contentHolder").droppable();
});
```

[JSFiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/antisilent/7Lsbknw3/33/)

Comment: Some more sources: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458817/jquery-ui-drag-and-clone-from-original-div-but-keep-clones), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948582/jquery-draggable-and-resizable), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349053/jquery-ui-on-drop-attach-the-div-to-its-droppable-target)

(EDIT: Formatting, links.)